# Starting SSIS Package over stored procedure where a Excel file will be imported

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We are trying to start a SSIS package with
`ssisdb.catalog.Create_execution` and `ssisdb.catalog.start_execution @execution_id`

This package has a data flow task where an Excel file will be imported.

The problem is, if we start it using any of these stored procedures, SSIS can't access the Excel file because the user which is used to access the file server is "Anonymous".

Does anybody know who we can change this that the user is not anonymous?

If we try it with a job and proxy it's working

Thank you

Comment: You need to enable Kerboros on the host running SQL Server; then the credentials of the (Windows) user connected to SQL Server, who starts the package execution, will be used to connect to the file path.

Comment: Does this approach help? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220177/how-do-i-execute-ssis-catalog-packages-as-a-different-user-with-tsql

Comment: Kerberos is on the MSSQLSERVER Instance enabled but not on MSSQLServerOLAPService. But I think this service is only for SSAS and not for SSIS. EXECUTE As does not help because the user will be not forwarded to the File Server

Comment: If you're running the stored procedures from a remote box, try calling them from a SQL Agent job instead, and you can avoid Kerberos delegation.

Comment: Hey our sec. team doesn't allow to call a job (don't ask why) thats why we are calling the ssis directly